# Vue reading data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, settimeout, custom-data-attribute

How can I sync variable "counter" inside VUE reading value from 'data-val' Attribute? In this example I use a setTimeout to change the data-* attribute value. My solution is calling a refresh() method by @mousemove event.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   counter: 1
  },
 template: '<div id="wrapper" @mousemove="refresh"><div id="el1" :data-val="counter">Value: {{ counter }}</div></div>',
  watch: {
   counter: function(val, oldVal){
     this.counter = val;
    }
  },
methods: {  refresh() { 
           this.counter = document.getElementById('el1').getAttribute("data-val"); 
             }
       }
});

 
var i=1;
timer = setInterval(changeDOM, 1500);
function changeDOM() {
 i++;
  el=document.getElementById('el1');
  el.setAttribute("data-val", i);
  console.log(el.getAttribute("data-val"));
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: aqua;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There would many ways yo achieve your goal but if you want out of vue instance You need to assign vue instance in a variable like below

```
var app = new Vue({
```

And then change `counter` as `app.counter`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   counter: 1
  },
 template: `<div id="el1" :data-val="counter">
  <div>Value: {{ getCounter }}</div>
  <div><input type="text" v-model="counter"></div>
  </div>`,
  computed: {
   getCounter: function(val, oldVal){
     return this.callMethod1(this.counter);
    }
  },
  methods:{
      callMethod1: function(){
         console.log("callMethod1 called with counter value : "+this.counter);
         return this.counter;
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The setTimeout was just an example. I have no influence who or what is changing the data-val attribute (maybe by external scripts or user). I like to "watch" the data-val attribute inside VUE and call a method getting the actual value once it was changed.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check once again. And if this answer not meet your requirement then add more info in your question.

Comment: If I insert back the setTimeout changing the "data-val" attribute it doesn't sync with the shown Value: {{counter}}.

Comment: I am sorry why you want both way with vue way can trigger easily. no need to use `setTimeout`

Comment: I have no influence in the main script that is creating the data-* attribute. I just use VUE to write a plugin working with the exisiting code.My solution right now is not nice and has bad performance. I use is a <body @mousemove="refresh"> to call this function: methods: {  refresh() { 
                       this.counter = $('#el1').attr('data-val'); 
                      }
}